# python collections.defaultdict() compile error

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

The following code, simple and clear enough, produces an error when compiled:

```
import string
import collections

#create dictionary with alphabets as keys, and empty values
list = ['aema', 'airplane', 'amend']

gen_dict = dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, '')

gen_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

for x in list:
    gen_dict['a'].append(x)
```

and the error produced is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "indexdict.py", line 14, in <module>
    gen_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
TypeError: first argument must be callable
```

any idea? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you overwrite the internal `list`, being the name of a type, with your `list = ['aema', 'airplane', 'amend']` above. Rename your `list` to e.g. `keys` or `keylist` and all will be fine.

So replace

```
list = ['aema', 'airplane', 'amend']
```

with

```
keys = ['aema', 'airplane', 'amend']
```

and

```
for x in list:
```

with

```
for x in keys:
```

Comment: @Manny - This is absolutely the right answer.  The OP has reassigned `list` in the local scope, which is producing the error.  The OP needs to use something like `myList` or `keylist` or something similar.  By the time the call to `collections.defaultdict` takes place `list` is no longer a function.

Comment: @Manny: No, it takes a callable. OP wants to use the builtin `list` which is not available any longer.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, I misinterpreted what was going on here.

Comment: @glglgl I tried the above adjustment of renaming the list to keys and I must say the error persists. This is it now:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "indexdict.py", line 14, in <module>
    gen_dict = collections.defaultdict(keys)
TypeError: first argument must be callable

Comment: @sys_debug This is what I assumed glglgl was suggesting (simply replacing _all_ instances of list, including the defaultdict call, so you don't redefine it), but my assumption was wrong. You have to pass the actual `list` function, not a list instance. So the correct call would be `collections.defaultdict(list)`, assuming you don't redefine `list`.